Request stuck until it gets timeout
I have this piece of code below to send a request to an address that does a 302 redirect to another subdomain. This webpage requires 4 HTTP headers to be present and when using curl (both locally and on our server), I get the correct response, however, with .net 7/8 app the httpClient.SendAsync method gets stuck and times out. The same code works locally, but does not work on our server.
How can I understand what is going on in this specific remote environment?
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://myhiddenaddres");
        
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br, zstd");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

This is the curl that works both locally and remote:
curl -k -i --raw "https://myhiddenaddres" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geck
o) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/we
bp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd" -H "Accept
-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9"


Please read: Even if the specification requires the method (and the body) not to be altered.... conclusion do not use 302, but use 307

I did not create the page. My code is just for the client part

Please debug your application, and check if those 4 HTTP headers are present when the request is coming from the .net app....

I created a test server to inspect that. The 4 headers are there

add debugging/logging info to your .net 7/8 app, and find out why it gets stick and time s out. There is not enough information to help you any further, because guessing is not an option on stackoverflow (or at least it's not an option for me.... )

I'd love to give you more info, because helping you guys understand may help me get the answer, however, debugging doesn't give any additional info. Just the stack trace showing where it's failing, the SendAsync. The error, timeout.
But I'll get back here to share my findings. I hope so
